# What is the difference between a REST resource (document, collection, store) and REST controller?

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

Rule: A verb or verb phrase should be used for controller names (https://medium.com/@cagline/restful-web-services-ddafb8019f2e)

Endpoint naming for resource must be nouns where as for controller it should be verb. So I am trying to unberstand what is difference between REST resource (document, collection, store) and REST controller.

Answer (score 1):

I read the article you linked to and I don't agree with all of its content or the "rules" the author has listed. **There are no hard-and-fast rules to REST API design**. Also, there is no concept of "Controllers" in more formal documents describing REST because it's an *implementation concern* : you can build a RESTful API in other platforms without using the Controller+Action paradigm.

Another issue is one of terminoloy: in some platforms the term "controller" refers to a function or class-method rather than a class, in other platforms (like ASP.NET Web API) a Controller is *not* a class-method but refers to the parent class and its methods are called **Actions**).

To answer your specific question:

> So I am trying to unberstand what is difference between REST resource (document, collection, store) and REST controller.

In short (and over-simplified): a *resource* accessed over a RESTful API generally is a noun, such as a business/domain entity (e.g. "Users", "Orders", "Products") or a system service (an SMTP service that sending emails).

In ASP.NET Web API, a Controller is a class that groups logically related Actions - but a Controller does not have limit itself to only performing actions on a single entity type - and multiple Controllers can have Actions for the same entity type.

Controller Action names are arbitrary in ASP.NET Web API (and ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC) because you decorate them with `[Route]` attributes that declare the URL path which can be anything you want.

For example, in a recent ASP.NET Core Web API project I built, I put "list" operations in a separate controller because actions for listing didn't have much in-common with actions for GET, POST and PATCH which were in their own separate controllers:

```
class ProductsListController : ApiController
{
    [Route("/products")]
    IActionResult GetAll( /* optional querystring params */ )

    [Route("/products/categories/{categoryName}")]
    IActionResult GetInCategory( String categoryName, /* optional querystring params */ )
}

class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [Route("/products/{productId}")]
    IActionResult Get( Int32 productId )

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/products/{productId}")]
    IActionResult Post( Int32 productId )
}
```

However, in a completely different project that was not using ASP.NET Web API (but was actually running on .NET Framework 2.0 (*long story*) I built a RESTful API using `.ashx` files and a creative use of ASP.NET WebForm's routing engine and had a separate class for each action/endpoint (to make the best use of dependency-injection), like so:

```
// `MyRouteAttribute`, `MyHandler`, and `MyActionResult` are classes that belong to a mini-web-service library I wrote that can be hosted within ASP.NET WebForms but also ASP.NET Core and even completely outside of ASP.NET too.

[MyRoute( "GET", "/products")]
[MyRoute( "GET", "/products/categories/{categoryName}")]
class ProductsListHandler : MyHandler
{
    MyActionResult ProcessRequest( HttpContext httpContext )
}

[MyRoute( "GET", "/products/{productId}")]
class ProductsGetHandler : MyHandler
{
    MyActionResult ProcessRequest( HttpContext httpContext )
}

[MyRoute( "POST", "/products/{productId}")]
class ProductsPostHandler : MyHandler
{
    MyActionResult ProcessRequest( HttpContext httpContext )
}
```

Comment: If the 'thing' accessed over the api endpoint is not a business/domain entity. For example: Lets say the endpoint is a process. For example: Extraction - so here there is no CRUD. Assume input is a document and output is JSON showing 1st line in the document. Then would it be a REST resource [use Noun] (document, collection, store) or a REST controller [use verb]?

Comment: @variable What is "Extraction"?

Comment: Extraction is an endpoint - that takes as input a document and output is JSON showing 1st line in the document. What is the REST resource in this case - is it the functionality (extraction) or the (input) document?

Comment: @variable For that I would just have `POST /services/extractor`. Or if there are multiple extraction operations then `POST /services/extractor/first-line`, for example.

Comment: Ok so the endpoint name (resource) should be based on functionality (extractor) rather then the input (document) - is this a rule? Also, do you think I can just use POST /extract-first-line ?

Comment: @variable Correct, because there is no persistent "document" on the server. And `POST /extract-first-line` sounds fine too - but I'm wary of putting resources in the website root.

Comment: If the API is a microservice solely responsible for extraction, and the API name is "http://line-extractor/api/" - then http://line-extractor/api/extract-first-line sounds better than http://line-extractor/api/extractor/extract-first-line (to avoid repeating the 'extractor' word) ?